# Working with modules python

Tags: python, import, module

I'm scratching my head to refactor a project written in Python.

The overall structure looks as follows:

```
library:
   codepackage1
   codepackage2
   scripts
```

There is a setup script which adds all files in the scripts folder to the bin. It also defines packages library, library.codepackage1 and library.codepackage2.

The problem is that each which needs to use another package uses the following identifier:

```
import library.codepackage1
```

Both modules in the codepackages as well as scripts are using this method.

This works fine, but requires

```
python setup.py install
```

to install all the packages to be later imported by running scripts and modules.

I would like to separate scripts and modules, so that I can run and test my changes without needing to reinstall the package in the system.

How should I go about this?

Comment: A hacky way is as follows: first your edit a file in the source repo, then find out where that file is installed, then overwrite it with the edited file. If you change many source files, then it makes sense to re-install.

Comment: no, that's not what I'm after. I know exactly where the file is installed. I would like to have a dev loop where I don't need to wait to package a distribution to run the program locally. Ideally when running it from the main in codepackage2 I should be able to reference other packages without installing

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked PYTHONPATH? If the path to the packages is at the top od sys path, then python will take it from your location.

To check it at runtime:

```
import sys
print '\n'.join(sys.path)
```

To force using packages from given location instead of pip's or whatever default location:

```
# script_that_imports_library.py
import sys, os
THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sys.path.insert(0, THIS_DIR)

#  or if it is e.g. one level above:
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(THIS_DIR))
import library

#  to check where it's imported from:
print 'the library comes from: %s' % library.__file__
```

Comment: reading the python docs, it says that modules should be resolved first by their relative location, then by the module.

"If the imported module is not found in the current package (the package of which the current module is a submodule), the import statement looks for a top-level module with the given name."

Comment: I haven't seen this hack in any libraries, so either my package structure is wrong, or my use case is different.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I found out that setup.py has a develop option, which creates a symbolic link to the repository.

This way you can use top level imports, and they will be resolved both in development and production.